# How resolve BeanCreationException and Injection of autowired dependencies failed error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, javabeans, autowired

I got this error while I `autowire` with my `JpaRepository` classes.
I try to save a data. Then I got following error.

Here is my error.....

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cutomerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.nought.service.MyDBService com.nought.controller.CutomerController.myDBService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.nought.service.MyDBService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Here is my `CutomerController` class....

```
@Controller
public class CutomerController {

    @Autowired
    public MyDBService myDBService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCutomer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addCustomer() {
        return "add-customer";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("addCustomer")
    public Customer construct() {
        return new Customer();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doRegister(@ModelAttribute("addCustomer") Customer customer) {
        myDBService.saveCustomer(customer);
        return "success";
    }

}
```

Here is my Repository class....

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer,Integer> {

}
```

Here is my Service class.....

```
@Service
public class MyDBService {


    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }


}
```

Here is my `applicationContext.xml` .....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nought">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="emf">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.nought.entity" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <import resource="security.xml"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.nought.repository"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" />

</beans>
```

Comment: What's the import statement in MyDBService for the `@Service` annotation? And why are you specifically excluding the `Controller` annotation from your `component-scan`?

Comment: My project data save via Service classes....
I have repository classes for each entity..
Then I use those service classes to save data